# what is the different git :// and git+https://?

Tags: node.js, git

I want to add a git repository to my package.json.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "dep1": "git+https://url1",
        "dep2": "git://url1"        
}
```

When I run dep1 it worked for and dep2 failed.
What is the diffrerent between `git+https` and `git://`?
Does it is the same result ?
Do I need to add something to .git?

Comment: Perhaps that's the difference of an HTTPS reference and an SSH?

Comment: @SterlingArcher No, the `git` protocol has **nothing to do** with `ssh` - you're probably thinking about `git+ssh` - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667190/what-is-the-different-git-and-githttps/48667405#48667306) below.

Comment: Probably, I didn't google very hard :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several protocols you can use to reference your dependencies in package.json:

**git,
git+ssh,
git+http,
git+https** and 
**git+file**

As always, there are pros and cons of all of the protocols.

The difference is that with `git:` you're using the native git protocol and with `git+https:` you're accessing a git repo over HTTPS (you could also use SSH instead of HTTPS, for example, but the server needs to support it).

The **git** protocol is very fast but it lacks authentication or encryption.

The **git+https** is nice for public repos and it works well with proxies and firewalls but if you need authentication then you need to provide username and password.

The **git+ssh** is good for private repos because it uses your ssh public keys for authentication and no passwords need to be entered.

The **git+file** is for referencing repos on your own filesystem, usually local files but it can also be used with remote files with SMB or NFS.

Now, if you want to **change** `git+http` to `git` then it will work **only** if you have a git server installed and listening on the same host and serving the same repos.

It's like changing `http:` to `ftp:` in a URL - it will work **only** if you have an FTP server installed on the same host and **serving the same files**.

The **bottom line** is that you can use **only those protocols that the server supports**.

See the docs:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: Thanks , When I tried to change git+https:// to git: then it failed .Do I need to do more steps for the convert ?

Comment: @user1365697 What are you trying to do and why? Does it work with `git clone` directly?

Comment: @user1365697 For `git:` to work you need to have a git server installed and listening on the standard port. for the `git+https:` you only need a web server. It's like changing `http:` to `ftp:` - it will work only if you have an FTP server installed on the same host and serving the same files. The same is here - it will work only if you have a git server installed and serving the same repos.

Answer (score 1):

Reference question https://askubuntu.com/questions/858711/what-is-the-meaning-of-githttps-github-com.

"It means the connection can use both the http and git protocols. The protocols are explained [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)."

Essentially you are just adding the ability for git to use HTTPS for transferring data. More detail is contained in the link.

Answer (score 1):

your dep1 is the https protocol and the git protocol

`dep1": "git+https://url1"`

your dep 2 is just the git protocol

`dep2": "git://url1:`

The reason you were able to succesfully use dep1 and not dep2 is because you are operating with a web server that authenticates over https. You appear to not be dealing with a git server, thus dep2 is redundant and can be removed.

As to not reinvent the wheel or semi-plagiarize others. Here are some good reads for those interested.

This is a length read on git protocols if interested.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

This provides a good tl;dr understanding of the protocols.
https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747

Answer (score 1):

It indicates to the NPM package manager that you wish to use git, with a repository URL of `https://url1`.

> `<protocol>` is one of `git`, `git+ssh`, `git+http`, `git+https`, or `git+file`.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

If you were talking directly to git, you would just say `git clone https://url1`, but NPM can use other protocols like `file:`, or `https:` to download a tarball over plain HTTPS. Other package managers like `pip` [support this pattern as well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858711/what-is-the-meaning-of-githttps-github-com).